# Angular http request return null in chrome but works in firefox

Tags: angular, rest, httpclient, angular7

I have faced a strange problem. I have been working for two months with this angular 7 project. Everything was working fine. But suddenly all my HTTP returns null. But it works as expected in Firefox. i reinstall chrome and problem disappear but after a day it starts again. we are using laravel as backend API.
status code is 200. but returns null. it is happening in each API (GET, POST).
I have tried in another PC and same thing. doesn't work in chrome, works in Firefox. Can anyone explain?
service:

```
getRecentProjects () {
  return this.http.get(`${ApiUrl}/ati-erp-project`);  
}
```

component:

```
this.homeService.getRecentProjects().subscribe(
      (success: any) => {
        console.log(success)
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
```

Comment: Can you show us a code snippet which HTTP request returns null?

Comment: Service:
getRecentProjects () {
    return this.http.get(`${ApiUrl}/ati-erp-project`);
  }
component:
this.homeService.getRecentProjects().subscribe(
      (success: any) => {
        console.log(success);
      }, (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )

this is just one simple example..its happening in every single req

Comment: Do you have any CORS related errors when trying to use those HTTP requests in Chrome?

Comment: yes, i use cors browser plugin in chrome and firefox, otherwise it throws cors error

Comment: Are you opening your HTML documents directly from the browser or are you serving your code via a webserver on localhost?

Comment: using angular cli serving in localhost:4200

Comment: Try giving this example a chance:
 getRecentProjects () {
    const apiURL = `${ApiUrl}/ati-erp-project`;
    
    return this.http.get(apiURL, {
      observe: 'response',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
      responseType: 'text' as 'text'
    }).catch(this.handleError);  
  }

Comment: i am afraid this catch operator from rxjs is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly. its a CORS issue. I have been tackling CORS issue with plugin for a long time specially when my back end don't have any headers or permission. But suddenly even after activation of CORS plugin HTTP response was null. when we configured back end with authorization header it works again. 
So, maybe its new policy for chrome its doesn't show you an error of CORS when you use plugin but returns null in response body.